# SimpleCV Color Spaces not changing

Tags: python, simplecv

Right now i am using python and taking an image with simplecv from my raspberry pi with the raspi cam but the R and B values are reversed. I saw in the image that blue is orange and wood is blue. I researched how to do it and i cam up with this code:

```
from SimpleCV import *

cam = Camera()

time.sleep(3)

img = cam.getImage().flipVertical().flipHorizontal().toRGB()

img.save('/home/pi/Documents/colortest.png')
```

This though, does not work, it looks the exact same as if i didnt add the

```
.toRGB()
```

It seems as it didn't even recognize the function call and leaves the image as it would be without then function call. 
So I need help changing the color space to RGB because it is not changing

Comment: could you add more detail, how does the images look, or how does the data does not change?

Comment: I edited the post now